# Python3: Download DOM from webpage with username/password

Tags: python, http, passwords, request

I am trying to download the DOM from the Yahoo fantasy football page. The data requires a yahoo user. I am looking for the python library where I can add my user/pass to the request.

urllib has [HTTPBasicAuthHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) which needs a [HTTPPasswordMgr Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#http-password-mgr)

the add_password field says I am missing an argument, when I try and pass it the 4 it wants. I am not sure what to put for the realm. I am new to Python.

I have found the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to look promising, but when I install it, it throws an error and I can not import it properly :\

I was hoping this was a bit easier to do in Python!

```
import urllib.request
try:
    url = "http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/" 
    username = "un"
    password = "pw"

    pwObj = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgr.add_password("http://yahoo.com",url, username, password)
    request = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwObj)

    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    print(result.read())


except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
# Error: add_password() missing 1 required positional argument: 'passwd'
```

The ideal solution would have someone downloading yahoo DOM data from a page that requires credentials :)

Comment: Are you sure that this site uses HTTP basic authentication? It's probably using some form of session based authentication. Do you have a link to an authenticated page?

Comment: Yeah, the solution I am working with uses Selenium to spoof a browser.

Comment: Not sure what Selenium has to do with whether the site uses HTTP basic auth vs. session based auth, but, since you're using Selenium, why don't you use that to login and scrape whatever data you want from the page?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import urllib.request
try:
    url = "http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/" 
    username = "_username"
    password = "_password"

    password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    password_mgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)
    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
    opener.open("http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/leaderboard")
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    result = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    print(result.read())


except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

But, how to run java events ?

Comment: I am able to get the request to send off and return properly :) But the response page seems to return data from a logged out page. :\

Comment: can you elaborate on the java events?

Comment: How to run `jquery,Java,Ajax` command ? You need analyze all server `skeleton` for using. External forms, incoming packets, data types, encrypted system etc. Use browser style access, you want write a browser for only yahoo ?